# How to find a lognormal distribution which mimics the shape of a given normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, monte-carlo, sampling-theory, bootstrap-sampling

Question:
If I give you the mean vector and the covariance matrix of a multivariate gaussian distribution (call it G1),
is there a way to find a lognormal distribution which mimics the shape of G1?

I mean,
such a lognormal distribution has an underlying multivariate gaussian distribution (call it G2).
Is there an analytic solution, such that the mean and covariance of G1 can be converted to those of G2?

Thank you very much indeed in advance!

PS.
Of course, multivariate gaussian and lognormal are different, I just try to see if it is possible find a lognormal which mimic the multivariate gaussian as much as possible.

A relevant question is below too,

https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/find-lognormal-distribution-which-mimics-a-given-normal-distribution/5094?u=crquantum

but wanted to have some ideas on stackexchange too.

Comment: So you want to "mimic" in the sense of having the same mean & covariance matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited the content and title. I mean the lognormal needs to mimic the shape of a given multivariate gaussian. You know the lognormal needs to be look like a  a given multivariate gaussian as much as possible.

Comment: That's a bit vague. If $f,\,g$ are the respective MG & log-normal PDFs, maybe you want to minimize $\int_{\Bbb R^n}(f-g)^2d^nx$, where $n$ is the dimension of their mutual support.

Comment: Thank you very much! The squared difference integral you mentioned is indeed very inspiring! Is there some papers or references which did similar things with what you mentioned? Or in general, is there some papers or references that may shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Is there some analytic equations which can somehow relate the MG $f$ with the log-normal PDF $g$?

Comment: To mimic a PDF $f$ on $\Bbb R^n$ with whichever PDF $g_\alpha$ in an $\alpha$-parameterized family minimizes $\int_{\Bbb R^n}(g_\alpha-f)^2d^nx$ by choosing a suitable $\alpha\in\Bbb R^p$, we solve $p$ simultaneous equations $\int_{\Bbb R^n}(g_\alpha-f)\partial_{\alpha_i}g_\alpha d^nx=0$.

Comment: This is awesome explanation, thank you so much!